# How to say "<noun> is more/better/greater than <noun>"

Tags: grammar

How would I say something like this:

- Cars are better than bicycles.
- There are more bicycles than there are cars.
- Running is faster than walking.
- Dying is worse than eating breakfast.

Is there any special grammatical form for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Korean Comparatives and Superlatives: 더, 보다, 가장/제일](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit1/unit-1-lessons-17-25-2/lesson-19/). It goes into a lot more detail of various forms, but for your specific examples, they can actually all work with the common `A보다 B이/가 더 DV` pattern:

Cars are better than bicycles.
자전거**보다** 자동차가 **더** 나아요.

There are more bicycles than there are cars.
자전거**보다** 자동차가 **더** 많아요.

Running is faster than walking.
걷는 것**보다** 달리기가 **더** 빨라요.

Dying is worse than eating breakfast.
아침을 먹는 것**보다** 죽는 것이 **더** 나빠요.

Note, I purposely translated these rather directly and in a grammatically consistent way to display the pattern, so some of them might be slightly awkward, but of course I welcome a native speaker to make any edits.

Comment: I think the translation is good.  One point worth mentioning is that 더 is **optional** when we already have -보다.  In each example sentence above, we can remove 더 and the sentence keeps the same meaning.  (This is, of course, in contrast to English where comparisons must be expressed with comparative forms "-er".)

Comment: @jick Thanks for checking them, and adding that note about 더.